Does the SailBeam concept violate conservation of etendue?
SailBeam is a proposed method of spacecraft propulsion based on laser-driven sails. The SailBeam laser pushes on a series of "microsails," each sail having around 0.1m radius. Each microsail is made of a thin dielectric mirror which is very reflective, and that allows it to withstand very high laser intensity without melting, so it can reach near lightspeed in under a second over a distance of around 100,000 km. The microsails coast for a long time and then slam into the spacecraft, accelerating it. This is proposed to accelerate the spacecraft to 0.1c or faster over about 10 years.
My question is about how the laser is meant to be focused in the following diagram:

Here we see the laser emitter (green square) producing a beam with high divergence. This beam spreads out until it reaches a lens (white oval). The lens focuses the beam onto the sail (green oval).
It's not specified where the lens is located in relation to the emitter, but presumably the lens is close to the emitter (?). It's supposed to focus an initially high-divergence beam onto a target that could be up to 100,000 km away. The picture shows the beam converging, rather than diverging, from the lens onto the target.
Doesn't this violate conservation of etendue? Because the divergence/convergence angle looks to be a lot smaller at the sail than it is at the emitter, with presumably comparable area to the emitter.
And why does "size of lens" matter for focusing a laser onto a small spot at long distances? I don't see how it improves the situation, unless the target you are "focusing" onto is larger than the lens itself, so that the beam can diverge (and not converge) from the lens to the target.  Here's a diagram I drew to illustrate the concept:

Maybe the SailBeam diagram is just misleading and the lens is supposed to be more like halfway between the emitter and sail, or maybe the lens is just drawn too big and the beam would continue to diverge after the lens. But then I'm not sure how they are going to maintain focus on an 0.1m sail at 100,000 km (with a 1µm wavelength laser).

Edit: I think it does not violate conservation of etendue. See this revised diagram:

Since the angle $\theta$ is the same at the emitter and target, and the area of emitter and target is the same, this optical system should be theoretically possible, and I think that's the kind of setup SailBeam is intended to use.

I don't know where you got that 1cm focal point diameter from. That sounds off by orders of magnitude for a laser.

@FlatterMann Sorry, 1cm is the aperture size, the laser is aimed left to right at a sail 0.1m on the right

That's the problem with the diagram. It's not an incoherent 1cm source.

@FlatterMann I think I've figured it out. See my revised diagram: it does not violate conservation of etendue.
